# Vticker plugin and Twitter plugin (jTweetAnywhere) not working together.

Tags: plugins, twitter, vticker

I would like my twitter feed to be displayed using Vticker (one tweet at a time is shown, fades up and another appears in its place). I used the directions on the site (http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/) which shows you how to use Vticker with another plugin, but it is not working. It seems that my twitter feed is correctly being displayed, but not being utilized by the Vticker. Chrome is not displaying any errors. Any ideas?

Code:
JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
   username: 'twitternamehere',
   count: 5
   }).ajaxStop(function(){
  $('.tweets').vTicker({
   speed: 500,
   pause: 3000,
   showItems: 1,
   animation: 'fade',
   mousePause: false,
   height: 0,
   direction: 'up'
 });
 });    
 });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/

I used the Rich Hollis version of vTicker to replace Google's abandoned Google News "newsshow"  feature for embedding custom Google News in blogs and web sites:

http://www.gooplusplus.com/news-frame-guide.html

My javascript knowledge is fairly basic but I can hint at a few things you might try.

First, the richhollis jquery.vticker.min.js did not work for me but his uncompressed jquery.vticker.js did work. (I made my own min.js version via http://jscompress.com/ )

Second, your $('.tweets').etc might need to be $('#tweets').etc if referring to a <DIV> ??

You can look through my sample vticker-based HTML source code here:

http://www.gooplusplus.com/dark-nopic.html?snc&box#Science-News